# Splitting a function prototype of two lines

Tags: algorithms, gap

I am trying to write a function in pseudocode that does not seem to appear properly due to its length. Is there a way to split the function prototype over two lines so that there is no gap as shown in the figure?

[image]

This is my code

```
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\let\oldReturn\Return
\renewcommand{\Return}{\State\oldReturn}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{myLongFunction}{$parameter1,parameter2, parameter3$}
    \If {$balblabla$} 
        \State $bla1$
    \Else
        \State $bla2$
    \EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to new site of TeX.SE. Please, could you add your `\documentclass` and other packages?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 \Function{myLongFunction}{\newline$parameter1,parameter2, parameter3$}
```

[image]